# Linear transformations and matrix basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Hello I am currently stuck on this problem:

[image]

I have no idea how to start part (i).

Any help to get me started?

Comment: Calculate $T(1,1)$. Call it $(a,b,c)$. How can you write $(a,b,c)$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors of $B'$; that is, what do $d,e,f$ need to be so that $d(1,0,0) + e(1,-1,0) + f(1,1,1) = (a,b,c)$?

Comment: $T(1,1)=(1,3,-1)$ so $f=-1,e=-4,d=6$? I'm not sure how that helps me though?

Comment: do the same for $T(0,1)$. Your matrix $T$ will contain the $d,e,f$ from this and the previous comment

Comment: So here $T(0,1)=(-1,3,2)$ so $d=-4,e=-1,f=2$ what now?

Comment: What does it mean to write a matrix of a transformation relative to some bases? (consult your textbook or notes if needed) For an easier example, if $B$ and $B'$ were the *standard* bases ($(1,0), (0,1)$ and $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$) what could you say about the relationship between the columns of $A$ and the images $T(1,0)$ and $T(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1):

Call $X$ a column vector in the canonical basis of $\mathbf R^2$, $X'$ its column vector of coordinates in basis $\mathcal B$, and $P$ the change of basis matrix from the canonical basis to basis $\mathcal B$. We have 
$$X=PX'.$$
Similarly, let $Y$ be a column vector in the canonical basis of $\mathbf R^3$, $X'$ its column vector of coordinates in basis $\mathcal B'$, and $Q$ the change of basis matrix from the canonical basis to basis $\mathcal B'$. We have:
$$Y=QY'. $$

If $Y=TX$, we have:
$$QY'=TPX'\iff Y'=(Q^{-1}TP) X', $$
so the matrix of $T$ after the changes of basis in $\mathbf R^2$  and $\mathbf R^3$ is:
$$T'=Q^{-1}TP.$$